# Adding an integer to a string in C, how to understand the result?

Tags: c, string, pointers

How does the output turns out to be morning.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    printf(5+"Good Morning");
    return 0;
}

output is Morning
```

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`. You should have gotten a warning, probably on `void main()`, and also on `return 0;`. Do not ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: so many questions could be avoided if people actually _read_ the warnings and took action (even if it's not the point here, it may be OP _next_ problem. And answerers should always try to compile the OP piece of code, and downvote if 453 warnings appear, one of them pointing out the problem :)

Answer (score 6):

Pointer arithmetic: you added 5 to the `char` array position, skipping the 5 first chars, i.e. `Good` and space.

It is legal as long as you don't exceed the size of the string, in that case, you have *undefined behaviour*

Comment: So it happened without even the declaring and initializing the char array?

Comment: you have declared _and_ initialized your char array: it is a _literal_.

Comment: @AnjaniKumar you implicitly declared a temporary, unnamed character array

Comment: And how does this one work out ? #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%c\n","abcdefgh"[4]);
    return 0;
}

Comment: you're extracting a character from your literal. It's not a string, it's not pointer arithmetic. It is legal as well :)

Comment: Yes, it prints the 5th char (starts at 0)

Comment: @artm: It's not temporary. The anonymous array object associated with a string literal has static storage duration, meaning that it (logically) exists during the entire execution of the program.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html -- In fact, reading the entire FAQ is bound to be more useful than trying to learn C in SO comments.